# Append child is printing [object Object] instead of content

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append a child, which happens to be the content of lista4, but it only prints [object object]. 
When I console log lista4, I get the whole thing (what I actually want)
I think that it has to do with the fact that lista4 is an object and I have to "translate" it to text.
Can you tell me how to do it? 
Thanks.

```
let lista4 = {  
        nombre: "Pablo", 
        apellido: "Rocho", 
        direccion: {
              ciudad: "Buenos Aires",
              pais: "Argentina"
        }
}

let campo = document.createElement("div")
campo.innerText = lista4
document.body.appendChild(campo)
```

I'm expecting to get the whole content of lista4, but I get [object object]

Comment: it's indeed an object. you need to use JSON.stringify(lista4) to convert it to string. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSON.stringify`, otherwise the `toString` method is called (which results in `[object Object]`.

```js
let lista4 = {
  nombre: "Pablo",
  apellido: "Rocho",
  direccion: {
    ciudad: "Buenos Aires",
    pais: "Argentina"
  }
};

let campo = document.createElement("div")
campo.innerText = JSON.stringify(lista4);
document.body.appendChild(campo)
```